# Can we connect to postgres sql instance database using cloud function which is in another project?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql, google-vpc

I want to connect to Postgres Database which is another project through cloud function but I am not able to do so using vpc connector.

I have done the below steps to set this up but still I am getting connection refused error.

Project A:

- I have a cloud function using one customise service account(e.g sa-project-account)
- I am routing all request through vpc connector

Project B

- I have postgres db having public ip, connection name
- Given Cloud SQL client permision to sa-project-account which is from project A

Still I am not able to connect? Any solution please.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to public IP? Why do you need a serverless VPC access connector?

Comment: Trying with both way..I am trying to access through Public IP or through  SQL connection name. Is it possible to get the connectivity privately from one project to another.?

Answer (score 1):

You may follow this to establish private connectivity between a Cloud Function in one project and a PostgreSQL database in another project.

VPC Peering:

Create VPC peering between the VPC network in Project A (Cloud Function) and Project B (PostgreSQL database). Ensure firewall rules allow necessary traffic between the peered VPC networks. Update Cloud Function to use the private IP address or internal DNS name of the PostgreSQL instance.

Reference: [Creating VPC Peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc-peering), [Configuring Private Google Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access)

Shared VPC:

Create a Shared VPC network in the host project (Project C) and attach it to the service project (Project A). Deploy Cloud Function within the VPC network of the service project. Configure firewall rules for inter-project communication. Use private IP addresses or internal DNS names for communication between Cloud Function and PostgreSQL.

Reference: [Using Shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc), [Deploying Cloud Functions with Shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/connecting-vpc#deploying_functions_in_a_shared_vpc)

IAM and Permissions:

Ensure appropriate IAM roles and permissions for Cloud Function's service account to access resources in the remote project (e.g., Cloud SQL instance in Project B).

Reference: [Understanding IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview), [Granting, Changing, and Revoking Access](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access)